# SELECT DISTINCT + ORDER BY additional expression

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, distinct

I have no experience with PostgreSQL and I am migrating a Rails5+MySQL application to Rails5+PostgreSQL and I am having a problem with a query.

I've already looked at some questions/answers and still haven't been able to solve my problem. My problem seems to be ridiculous, but I needed to ask for help here!

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.* FROM users 
INNER JOIN areas_users ON areas_users.user_id = users.id 
INNER JOIN areas ON areas.deleted_at IS NULL AND areas.id = areas_users.area_id 
WHERE users.deleted_at IS NULL AND users.company_id = 2 AND areas.id IN (2, 4, 5) 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN users.id=3 THEN 0 WHEN users.id=5 THEN 1 END, users.id, 1 ASC
```

Running the query in DBeaver, returns the error:

> ```
> SQL Error [42P10]: ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
> ```

What do I need to do to be able to use this `SELECT DISTINCT` with this `ORDER BY CASE`?

Comment: In a table called `users` I would expect all rows to have different ids. Why do you need DISTINCT?

Comment: depending on the JOINs, it may have duplicate users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's like error message says:

> ```
> for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
> ```

This is an expression:

```
CASE WHEN users.id=3 THEN 0 WHEN users.id=5 THEN 1 END
```

You cannot order by it, while doing `SELECT DISTINCT users.* FROM ...` because that only allows `ORDER BY` expressions that appear in the `SELECT` list.

Typically, the best solution for `DISTINCT` is not to use it in the first place. If you don't duplicate rows, you don't have to de-duplicate them later. See:

- [How to speed up select distinct?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/93159/3684)

In your case, use an [`EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) semi-join (expression / subquery) instead of the joins. This avoids the duplication. Assuming distinct rows in table `users`, `DISTINCT` is out of job.

```sql
SELECT u.*
FROM   users u
WHERE  u.deleted_at IS NULL
AND    u.company_id = 2
AND    EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM areas_users au JOIN areas a ON a.id = au.area_id
   WHERE  au.user_id = u.id
   AND    a.id IN (2, 4, 5)
   AND    a.deleted_at IS NULL
   )
ORDER BY CASE u.id WHEN 3 THEN 0
                   WHEN 5 THEN 1 END, u.id, 1;  -- ①
```

Does what you request, and typically much faster, too.

Using [simple ("switched") `CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) syntax.

① There is still an ugly bit. Using a positional reference in `ORDER BY` can be convenient short syntax. But while you have `SELECT *`, it's a really bad idea. If the order of columns in the underlying table changes, your query is silently changed. Spell out the column in this use case!

(Typically, you don't need `SELECT *` in the first place, but just a selection of columns.)

IF your ID column is guaranteed to have positive numbers, this would be a bit faster:

```sql
...
ORDER BY CASE u.id WHEN 3 THEN -2
                   WHEN 5 THEN -1
                   ELSE u.id END, <name_of_first_column>
```

#### I MUST use `DISTINCT`

(Really?) If you insist:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE u.id WHEN 3 THEN -2 WHEN 5 THEN -1 ELSE u.id END AS order_column, u.*
FROM   users u
JOIN   areas_users au ON au.user_id = u.id
JOIN   areas a ON a.id = au.area_id
WHERE  u.deleted_at IS NULL
AND    u.company_id = 2
AND    a.id IN (2, 4, 5)
AND    a.deleted_at IS NULL
ORDER  BY 1, <name_of_previously_first_column>;  -- now, "ORDER BY 1" is ok
```

You get the additional  column `order_column` in the result. You can wrap it in a subquery with a different `SELECT` ...

Just a proof of concept. Don't use this.

#### Or `DISTINCT ON`?

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (CASE u.id WHEN 3 THEN -2 WHEN 5 THEN -1 ELSE u.id END, <name_of_first_column>)
       u.*
FROM   users u
JOIN   areas_users au ON au.user_id = u.id
JOIN   areas a ON a.id = au.area_id
WHERE  u.deleted_at IS NULL
AND    u.company_id = 2
AND    a.id IN (2, 4, 5)
AND    a.deleted_at IS NULL
ORDER  BY CASE u.id WHEN 3 THEN -2 WHEN 5 THEN -1 ELSE u.id END, <name_of_first_column>;
```

This works without returning an additional column. Still just proof of concept. Don't use it, the `EXISTS` query is much cheaper.

See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: You write: `a larger query with some JOINs and does a different ordering with some CASEs, but to simplify the query:` Chances are, you removed the reason for your `DISTINCT` by over-simplifying. Or you do not need `DISTINCT` to begin with. Provide the original query, the (core) definition of `CREATE TABLE users ...` and your version of Postgres, in the question. If `DISTINCT` is actually meaningful, you need to define which row to pick from each set of duplicates. Then this should be solved swiftly.

Comment: Using the query I commented on in the question, the problem already happens, depending on the JOIN it can bring duplicate users, so I use DISTINCT. The original query is: ```SELECT DISTINCT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "areas_users" ON "areas_users"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "areas" ON "areas"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "areas"."id" = "areas_users"."area_id" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "users"."company_id" = 2 AND "areas"."id" IN (2, 4, 5) ORDER BY CASE WHEN users.id=3 THEN 0
WHEN users.id=5 THEN 1 END, users.id, 1 ASC```

Comment: I use this id = 3 and id = 5 because I need these records to come first

Comment: @Marcus: Please [edit] your question and add this query to it. I added a solution to my answer.

Comment: thx! Good tip of the negative number, I didn't know it's faster! Out of curiosity, in PostgreSQL there is no possibility to use DISTINCT in this query like MySQL? I ask because my API uses Rails `.distinct` by default

Comment: Sure, you can make your query work with `DISTINCT` if you insist. But that's a bad idea for this query. There are plenty of other good use cases. Or with the more versatile `DISTINCT ON`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860 Just like there are plenty of good use cases for a shotgun. But shooting yourself in the foot is not among them. If that "API" really uses `.distinct` by default, that's remarkably poor design.